Primacy of $\Delta G$ vs $\Delta H$ in Chemical Reactions
In section 5.1 of his 1999 text, "An Introduction to Thermal Physics, Schroeder states,

"As an example of using $\Delta G$, consider the chemical reaction
$$ \mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O} \to \mathrm{H}_2 + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{O}_2,...$$


"According to standard reference tables, $\Delta H$ for this reaction (at room temperature and atmospheric pressure) is 286 kJ... When we $form$ hydrogen and oxygen out of water, we need to put 286 kJ of energy into the system some way or other... of the 286 kJ needed, must we supply all as work, or can some enter as heat?...


"The amount of energy that must enter as electrical work is the difference between 49 [$T\Delta S$] and 286, that is, 237 kJ.
"This number, 237 kJ, is the change in the system's Gibbs free energy; it is the minimum "other" work required to make the reaction go."

Now, I've been fairly puzzled by this passage for some time. The second paragraph (ie the one beginning with "According to...") seems to suggest that the relevant quantity in determining whether a chemical reaction will occur is the change in enthalpy occurring during the process, as opposed to the change in Gibb's energy.
I interpret the passage as saying that a minimum of 286 kJ of energy must be put into the system to convert one mole of water into one mole of hydrogen gas and half a mole of oxygen gas.
Is this the case? Is it the change in $enthalpy$ that determines whether the reaction occurs or the change in $Gibbs$ $energy$?

the 286kJ refers to a reaction at constant temperature, likely room temperature, and then there is a 49kJ thermal energy exchange between the water and the atmospheric environment that supplies that energy, so that the remaining 286-49=237kJ is the Gibbs free energy change that the reaction needs to be supplied from an outside work source, for example, by a battery through electrolysis.

Here's a different approach using an open system at steady state.  The first law for an open system tells us that, per mole of water passing through the system, $$q-w=\Delta H^0$$where w is the electrical work per mole of water passing through the system.  For a single reservoir at the inlet water temperature T and a system operating reversibly, the 2nd law for an open system at steady state tells us that $$\frac{q}{T}=\Delta S^0$$So, combining these equations gives:  $$w=-(\Delta H^0-T\Delta S^)=-\Delta G^0$$and $$q=T\Delta S^0$$where q is the amount of heat that must be added to hold the control volume system at constant temperature T.

The Gibbs free energy change basically determines whether a reaction would occur spontaneously or non-spontaneously.
If Gibbs free energy is negative (i.e. some net energy is released in the reaction), the reaction is spontaneous i.e. it would happen on its own once it has been given its required activation energy (the thermal energy supplied).
If it's positive, then it requires some energy from outside source and doesn't go forward even after giving activation energy (heat) and requires extra energy to reach the end. So, it's non-spontaneous.

When we form hydrogen and oxygen out of water, we need to put $286\text{ }kJ$ of energy into the system some way or other... of the $286\text{ } kJ$ needed

As indicated in the paragraph, here the enthalpy change is $286\text{ } kJ$.
This enthalpy just determines how much energy change is occurring between reactant and product.
So, The Gibbs free energy determines whether a reaction would occur on its own or not (certainly after activation) and together with Enthalpy change, they determine: if it occurs spontaneously or non-spontaneously, how much energy is given out of or required in, other than the activation energy.
Like here, the Gibbs energy is positive ($237\text{ } kJ$, so the reaction required that much extra energy other than activation (thermal, $49\text{ } kJ$).
